# Excel formula Help if and vlookup

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 excel sheets ("sheet 1, sheet 2").

Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 have "product #" in column A and "quantity" in column B. I'm trying to write a formula that would allow Sheet 1 to lookup on sheet 2 if there is a Product # match In column A and if there is a product # match then to update on Sheet 1 Column B (quantity) the product quantity from sheet 2. If there is no Match of product # from sheet 2 then to return a zero in sheet 1 Column B (quantity).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP will return an error if no match so capture that and return `0`

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried that formula and I'm still getting a ''0'' on sheet 1 quantity even though there is a quantity on sheet 2 for the same product.

Comment: Then double check your spelling, making sure that one or the other does not have space or other unprintable characters in them that would cause it not to be the same, this is looking for an exact match.  Also, make sure if they are numbers that one is not a number stored as text, as they are different to Excel and not equal.

Comment: @senderrussell please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Can I just ask one more question pertaining to this? How can I highlight in red all Product # that are on sheet 2 that are not on sheet 1? Thanks for the help!

Comment: New questions get new posts.  Use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: In the =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),0) formula in an error scenario Is there a way to return the contents of another cell on sheet 2 instead of a zero?

Comment: Yes by that is new question and should get it's own post, but please try to do it on your own before posting.  Then post  a link to this question with what you have tried to modify this answer to your needs and where you are stuck.